# Member reference base type 'int' is not a structure

Tags: c++

I have a main.cpp which uses 2D array (it is named as Matrix2D in my code). I am trying to overload by implementing >> operator, this operator will be used with ifstream objects only(so not with cin etc.).

In my .h file I am trying to add a friend function to do the overloading.
The following is my code.

```
class Matrix2D {
    private:
        int rows, cols;
        int **data;
        int top; // for isEmpty() function in main
    public:
        // default constructor
        Matrix2D();
        // destructor
        ~Matrix2D();
        Matrix2D(const int &, const int &);
        int GetIndex(const int &, const int &) const;
        void SetIndex(const int &, const int &, const int &) const;
        // implementation of isEmpty member function
        bool isEmpty(void) const;
    
        // implementation of >> 
        friend std::istream& operator>> (std::istream& add, Matrix2D &intMatrix1)
        {
            int rows, cols;
            add >> rows.intMatrix1;
            add >> cols.intMatrix1;

            return add;
        }
};
```

However compiler is giving a syntax error. Says, "Member reference base type 'int' is not a structure or union".
I don't understand what it wrong, I did some research but I couldn't find anything related to my code.

Also, in my main.cpp I am calling two matrixes as;

```
Matrix2D intMatrix1;
Matrix2D intMatrix2;
```

and I am not allowed to make any changes on that since that is what professor said.

Answer (score 2):

```
add >> rows.intMatrix1;
```

should be

```
add >> intMatrix1.rows;
```

etc

The object goes to the left of the `.`, the member goes to the right.

Also it appears that `int rows, cols;` in your operator can be deleted.